# how to make the loops in two threads run together?

Tags: java, multithreading

im making a bomberman that works with sockets. have two threads, and both have loops. One is the game, and one is the client part of the game that sends and receive information form the server. i need that when an iteration in the client part is over (it already read and send all it needed to) it waits for the iteration on the game loop to end. then they start at the same time and so on.

is there a way of doing this? thank you beforehand.

Comment: Sounds like a job for`Semaphore` Man! :)

Comment: Or considering you've trigger event for each time you want to send data, maybe you can avoid the second thread and only call a function in order to send the data inside the first thread

Comment: @BtcSources - I had the game written that way. the problem is that the process of sending and receiving the data is relatively slow and it makes the game not fluid. thats why im trying to use threads.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I 100% understand your question, but just to throw some suggestions out there, synchronized(){} might help. Lets say your one thread wants to run the other, you have something like

```
Class2 class2=new Class2();
```

when you run the first thread, you have something like:

```
Class1 class1=new Class1();
```

you could then do, on class one, right before the loop(a little confusing):

```
//this tells class2 to wait
 synchronized(class2){
      class2.wait;
 }
```

and on class2:

```
 synchronized(class1){
      class1.wait;
 }
```

and then back to class1:

```
//this tells class2 to stop the wait FOR CLASS1, SO IT TELLS CLASS1 TO START
 synchronized(class2){
      class2.notify;
 }
```

and for class2:

```
//this tells class1 to stop the wait FOR CLASS2, SO IT TELLS CLASS2 TO START
 synchronized(class1){
      class1.notify;
 }
```

And you would end with:

```
//this tells class2 to wait
 synchronized(class2){
      class2.wait;
 }
//this tells class2 to stop the wait FOR CLASS1, SO IT TELLS CLASS1 TO START
 synchronized(class2){
      class2.notify;
 }
```

in class1, and

```
 synchronized(class1){
      class1.wait;
 }
//this tells class1 to stop the wait FOR CLASS2, SO IT TELLS CLASS2 TO START
 synchronized(class1){
      class1.notify;
 }
```

in class2

Hope I helped you, a little confusing. Have a nice day. That should make the two loops to start together, as for other waits and starts and do those together, play with the synchronized(){} and class.wait and class.notify, and you should be able to figure out the rest

Comment: Hight time to ditch `wait` and `notify` - things have improved 3 Java versions before.